# Asp.net Core Get Methods Under One Interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How can I get Method Under One interface like this:

**My service classes:**

**Module A**

```
public class CollectorA : ICollector
{
    public string CollectSomething()
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

**Module B**

```
public class CollectorB : ICollector
{
    public string CollectSomething()
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

**Module C**

```
public class CollectorC : ICollector
{
    public string CollectSomething()
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

**My ICollector interface:**

```
public interface ICollector
{
    string CollectSomething();
}
```

**My IModuleInitializer:**

```
public interface IModuleInitializer
{
    void Init(IServiceCollection serviceCollection);
}
```

Under Every Service I have ModuleInitializer like this

```
public void Init(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    serviceCollection.AddTransient<ICollector, CollectorA>();
    serviceCollection.AddTransient<ICollector, CollectorB>();
    serviceCollection.AddTransient<ICollector, CollectorC>();
}
```

How can I access for example in win console application this methods over this interface ?

My main class :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Get String Values each module and show on console ..
}
```

Comment: After the service provider has been built you can use `serviceProvider.GetServices<ICollector>()` extension method. Note it is `GetServices` (plural). It would return `IEnumerable<ICollector>` containing all the registered implementations.

Comment: Can you share some code here ? @Nkosi

Comment: I made an assumption about what you wanted but your question is still a bit unclear. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: For example my methodA doing sum of two number (2+4),methodB doing (3+5) ... I want call all of them in main application

Comment: I think the better implementation is to use the Factory Pattern or Strategy pattern no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following implementation

```
pubic class ModuleInitializer : IModuleInitializer{
    public void Init(IServiceCollection serviceCollection) {
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<ICollector, CollectorA>();
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<ICollector, CollectorB>();
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<ICollector, CollectorC>();
    }
}
```

and the other classes in the original question.

After the service provider has been built you can use `serviceProvider.GetServices<ICollector>()` extension method. Note it is `GetServices` (plural). It would return `IEnumerable<ICollector>` containing all the registered implementations.

The following example shows how to use the DI framework

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    var moduleInitializer = new ModuleInitializer();
    moduleInitializer.Init(services);
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    //Get String Values each module and show on console ..
    var collectors = serviceProvider.GetServices<ICollector>();
    foreach(ICollector collector in collectors) {
        Console.WriteLine(collector.CollectSomething());
    }
}
```

Comment: One question more :) All working but i m trying Add.Transient<...,...>(); automatically . In short i dont want use addTransient every module implementation. Any help thanks